# Is it possible to run a background process in next.js on a schedule?

Tags: node.js, next.js

When developing a service in next.js, it is necessary for the server to make certain requests to another server every day at 00:00. Is it possible to implement this in next.js without using third-party servers?

The next.js application will be deployed in a docker container to my server, without using vercel or similar services.

Comment: In a running nodejs process, you can use `setTimeout()` to schedule a function to be called at some time in the future.

Comment: @jfriend00, where? in the same process of nextjs? or create a new one?

Comment: Either one.  If you really want the scheduled operation to be completely out of your main process (perhaps because it uses a ton of CPU to process something), then put it in a different process.  But, if it's just an http request with minimal processing of the result, then you can easily just put it in your existing next.js process and nothing will be impacted by doing so.  You can get the current date/time, calculate how much time until then next midnight and call `setTimeout(fn, t)` with that number of ms so it will go at the next midnight.

Comment: After research I came to the conclusion that the best solution would be to run a separate cron process in parallel with next.js. I'm using node-cron.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible

Install node-cron

```
npm install node-cron
```

In your Next.js application, you might have a file like schedule.js:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
  console.log('Running a task every day at midnight');
});
```

Ensure this script is imported and executed on the server-side part of your Next.js application, such as in your server.js or in the getServerSideProps function.